# using v-for and v-bind:key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

by using v-for, i can not display the price and size.
How do I write v-for? and do i need v-bind:key?

I have tried to set v-bind:key but I could not really figure it out how to..

HTML

```
<tbody v-for="item in getMenyItems">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="option in item.options" v-bind:key="option.size">
            <td>{{ option.size }}</td>
            <td>{{ option.price }}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button">
                +
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Javascript

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        getMenyItems: {
          1: {
            name: "Margherita",
            description:
              "A delicious tomato based pizza topped with mozzarella",
            option: [
              {
                size: 9,
                price: 6.95
              },
              {
                size: 12,
                price: 10.95
              }
            ]
          },
        }
      };
    }
  };
```

I expect the size and price will be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your data. You have declared options in data but trying to iterate option. Change your data as below.

```
getMenyItems: {
    1: {
        name: "Margherita",
        description: "A delicious tomato based pizza topped with mozzarella",
        options: [
            {
                size: 9,
                price: 6.95
            },
            {
                size: 12,
                price: 10.95
            }
         ]
     }
}
```

And you can add the key to tbody as below.

```
<tbody v-for="item in getMenyItems" v-bind:key="item">
```

Comment: Thanks @itzVinoth! So dont I need to set v-for and v-bind to <tr> but only to <tbody> ?

Comment: You need to set v-for to iterate through the options. Wherever you're using the v-for directive, you need to set v-bind:key as well. Check the link https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object for detailed explanation on v-for.

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer if it solved your problem. It will be useful for people who run into same problem!

Comment: Hi @itzVinoth thank you for your comment, it has been really helpful! I should have been understood more about v-for and v-bind:key but now its more clear. Thanks a lot :) Hope this helps for other people.

Answer (score 2):

The above code can be write like this to access key and value from item object
This solves your issue

```
      <tbody v-for="(item, key, index) in getMenyItems" :key="key">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="(option, k, ind) in item.options" v-bind:key="ind">
            <td>{{ option.size }}</td>
            <td>{{ option.price }}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button">
                +
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Made changes to above code with :key in tbody, Is this working fine now?

Comment: Accept the above answer if this resolves your issue.., Thanks

Comment: Hi @chans thank you so much for your reply! Your solution solved this issue now. So each part where I want to iterate I need a v-for and v-bind:key right?

Comment: Alright, thanks! Can I ask one more question, what is the differences between `:key="key"` and `v-bind:key="ind"` ? @chans

Comment: Shorthand of v-bind:key is just :key , similarly shorthand of v-on:click is just @click

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be in ur 'getMenyItems'. Try this:

```
getMenyItems: [
      {
        name: "Margherita",
        description:
          "A delicious tomato based pizza topped with mozzarella",
        options: [
          {
            size: 9,
            price: 6.95
          },
          {
            size: 12,
            price: 10.95
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlepylunas to help for me!